# what are the settings required while maintainig logs in laravel ? and at which time I should use which severity level to maintain logs?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I am new for `Laravel` i want to manage logs of an application on hourly basis how do I do it ?
I want to know at which situation I use one of following Severity level.please explain exact use of it.

```
debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency.
```

what type of configuration we need to do ?

please guide me. thanks in advance. have a good day.

Comment: Have a look at [psr-3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) which implements [PSR-3 log levels](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md)

The eight severity levels supported by PSR-3 are based on [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424):

- **Emergency** – the system is unusable
- **Alert** – immediate action is required
- **Critical** – critical conditions
- **Error** – errors that do not require immediate attention but should be monitored
- **Warning** – unusual or undesirable occurrences that are not errors
- **Notice** – normal but significant events
- **Info** – just info you want to know from certain events
- **Debug** – detailed information for debugging purposes

All the rest you need to know is easily explained in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging).
There's no need for extra configuration. Only if you want to send those log to any third-party service in order to visualize organized reports, then you can use services like bugsnack, here's a [guide](http://goodheads.io/2015/12/20/how-to-handle-logs-and-reports-in-your-app-using-laravel-5-part-2/) I've used in the past.

Comment: boss how i manage these log messages to log file on hourly basis.

Comment: @mukundshelke what do you mean by "hourly basis"? You can set to create _single file logs_ in `config/app.php` setting `'log' => 'single'` (it's explained in the comments above the config) and then make some kind of backed when you parse these files, by hour. And remember you can always use the Monolog underlying class, hence it's API.